# React Array Filtering doesn't work properly

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api

```
export interface IActivity {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    category: string;
    date: Date;
    city: string;
    venue: string;
    isGoing: boolean;
    isHost: boolean;
    Attendees: IAttendee[]
}
```

[All Data Without Filtering only view activities attendees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfQmn.png)
When I try to see all data then Console Shows correct data. but when i try to filter specific data from array then it shows Undefined. Why `Host` is Undefined?

```
const ActivityListItem: React.FC<{activity: IActivity}> = ({activity}) => {
    const host = activity.Attendees.filter(a=> a.isHost)[0];
    console.log("Host ", host);
    return (
        <Segment.Group>
            <Segment>
```

without index[0] filter function return an empty array
[Without Index 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fxmA.png)

Please help me out. I'm stuck their, i tried others function but those function can't return my specific data.

Comment: What does it give you if you just put ```activity.Attendees.filter(a=> a.isHost)``` without ```[0]```?

Comment: It's possible it returns an empty array and you try to access index 0, which OFC would return undefined.

Comment: @RomainConstantin can you take a look, i had edited this post, added what's return without `[0]`

Comment: @DrewReese why return empty array? My data have correct format that while filtering this must not return empty array. Is their another reason to get empty array? Can you please elaborate

Comment: If no element has a truthy `isHost` property then no element will meet the condition and be returned. Essentially if this is the case then *all* the data is filtered out and an empty array will be returned from the array::filter function.

Comment: Thanks a lot @DrewReese Your last comment let me debug again for every components that connected with `isHost` And I found my bug, where i didn't mention to get boolean value. Thank you :)